# How can I show 404 error page when the ID is null?

Tags: database, codeigniter, isnull

I create a table in MYSQL. I insert some data into the table.

My question is about error when ID is NULL.

When the URL is ".com/blog/post/1" The content has ID 1 seen perfectly as well as the other ID's contents. But the problem is that I couldn't solve (because I am newbie in Codeigniter) when the url is ".com/blog/post" an error occurs.

I think the problem the "post/" needs and ID number after itself but how to change the error with a page like this shown below

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /post/ on this server.

Comment: can you post the code of controller `blog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `blog` controller when somebody calls for a `post` then you can check if `id` is there, if not you can redirect them to blog index.

The `blog` controller will look like this.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
   }

   function index()
   {
       //List posts with title and excerpts and a read more link
   }

   function post($id=NULL)
   {
       if($id)
       {
         //Show detailed post
       }
       else
       {
         redirect('blog');
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the ID to the function as a parameter; Like this;

```
public function post($id = false)
{
    if (!$id)
    {
        // No ID supplied
    }
    else
    {
        // ID found.
        // Carry on....
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.